# A solution of problem related to planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graph

I need an approaching method theoretically to solve the below problem.

> 4. (6pts.) For *n* ≥ 1 let *G<sub>n</sub>* be the simple graph with vertex set *V(G<sub>n</sub>) = {1, 2, ..., n}* in which two different vertices *i* and *j* are adjacent whenever *j* is a multiple of *i* or *i* is a multiple of *j*. For what *n* is *G<sub>n</sub>* planar?

Answer (score 1):

- Vertex 1 is adjacent to every other vertex (since any `j` is a multiple of `1`).
- Vertex 2 is adjacent to Vertices 1, 4, 6, 8, ...
- Vertex 3 is adjacent to Vertices 1, 6, 9, 12, ...
- Vertex 4 is adjacent to Vertices 1, 2, 8, 12, 16, ...
- etc.

Each vertex is adjacent to other vertices that are factors or multiples of its index.

A graph is non-planar if it contains a K<sub>5</sub> or K<sub>(3,3)</sub> minor therefore the problem reduces to what is the range of `n` values that does not contain one of those minors.

#### Forbidden Subgraphs

If you have a K<sub>(3,3)</sub> graph with the lowest vertices 1, 2, 4 in one sub-set of the complete bipartite graph then, for the vertices in the other sub-set to be adjacent they must be multiples of the lowest-common-multiple (LCM) of 1, 2 and 4 and the lowest possible (different) values are 8, 12 and 16. If you put any other values in the first sub-set then the LCM will be higher and so the maximum value will be higher; therefore 16 is the lowest possible `n` that will contain a K<sub>(3,3)</sub> subgraph.

If you have a K<sub>5</sub> graph and start with vertex 1 (2<sup>0</sup>) then the next lowest vertex it can connect to is vertex 2 (2<sup>1</sup>) and the next lowest vertex that both can connect to is a multiple of both previous vertex indices and the lowest would be vertex 4  (2<sup>2</sup>) and, following the same logic, the final vertices would be 8  (2<sup>3</sup>) and 16 (2<sup>4</sup>).

[image: K(5) and K(3,3) subgraphs in G16]

Therefore the lowest `n` is `16` for both a K<sub>5</sub> subgraph and a K<sub>(3,3)</sub> subgraph; giving the an initial bound on the range from 1 to 15.

---

#### Forbidden Minors

However, if you try to generate a planar embedding of a graph with 15 vertices you will find it is impossible.

This is because there is a K<sub>(3,3)</sub> minor (that is not immediately obvious) with the vertices 1, 2, 3 in one sub-set and in the other sub-set vertices 6 and 12, which are both trivially adjacent to all the vertices of the first sub-set, and then if you collapse the edges (5,10) and (5,15) then the resultant collapsed vertex is also adjacent to all the vertices of the first sub-set (since 1 is adjacent to 5, 10 and 15, 2 is adjacent to 10 and 3 is adjacent to 15).

[image: K(3,3) minor in G15]

It is possible to generate a planar embedding of *G<sub>14</sub>*:

[image: Planar Embedding of 14 Vertices]

Therefore, the Graphs with `n` from 1 to 14 have a planar embedding but any larger graphs are non-planar.